# Annotate is giving error in ggplot2 when using facet

Tags: r, ggplot2

I had previously used `annotate()` to add letters to facet panels of ggplots.  After updating `R` (to 3.6.1), code that had previously worked with annotate no longer does.

I can solve this by making a separate dataframe to label each facet, but that is cumbersome when I have a decent number of plots to make that vary in how many facets they have.  All I want is a letter (e.g., a-f) on each panel for identification in a journal article.

```r
library(ggplot2)

data(diamonds)

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat,y=price)) +geom_point()+ facet_wrap(~cut) + annotate("text",label=letters[1:5],x=4.5,y=15000,size=6,fontface="bold")

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat,y=price)) +geom_point()+ facet_wrap(~cut) + annotate("text",label=letters[1],x=4.5,y=15000,size=6,fontface="bold")
```

The first ggplot should produce a plot that has the facets labeled with lowercase letters.  Instead, I get the error:

> Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (25): label

The code does work if only one letter is used, as seen in the second ggplot, so annotate will work, but not with multiple values as it previously did.

Comment: Haven't dug into details, but I see an issue on github that seems related: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/3305

Answer (score 1):

I usually always use an external data frame for faceted annotations, because it is more traceable to me.

```r
df_labels=unique(diamonds[,"cut"])
df_labels$label=letters[as.numeric(df_labels$cut)] #to preserve factor level ordering
df_labels$x=4.5
df_labels$y=15000

ggplot(diamonds, aes(x=carat,y=price)) +
  geom_point()+ facet_wrap(~cut) + 
  geom_text(data=df_labels,aes(x=x,y=y,label=label))
```

Comment: I had found that "solution" already.  But it's just cumbersome when you have a decent number of figures with a different number of facets and different value ranges that need a single letter on each facet.

Comment: My answer should generate this automatically according to the number of facets. If you provide more data, maybe we could come up with an even more versatile solution